Impossible to delete Google Workspace
I have been trying for the past 10 days now to delete my entire google workspace account.
I am stuck on GCP has 1 resource that must be deleted. The only resource left is the org resource itself. I even tried turning off GCP for 30 days and I am still unable to delete workspace. I have gone through and cheked for hidden scripts, account access, deleting projects but I cannot get this org resource to delete. i even ran through the cloud resource manager script which says I have no active projects, folders or account access requests. There are no liens I am going crazy right now. I am half tempted to just turn everything off from the admin console and make my password 100 characters just never touch it again.

I’m voting to close this question because there is no way we can help you; you should ask Google support.
